# Command to find the folders modified on a particular date

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to find the folders that are modified on a particular date, month and year

i was able to find the files modified based on date and month. I also want to include the search based on year
ls -ltr | awk '$6 == "Aug" && $7 >=01 && $7 <= 31 &&  {print $9}'

Answer (score 1):

Try find.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +10 -mtime -12
```

will find files between 11 and 12 days old.

You just have to calculate the age but you are not limited to start of month.